# Using ActiveControl property with frames forwarding focus to subcomponents

Tags: delphi, focus

I have defined a `TFrame` descendant class and I want to forward the focus to a `TEdit` subcomponent.

[image: Picture of the frame in the IDE]

I've overridden the `SetFocus` method in order to forward the focus to the edit control:

```
  TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
    Edit1: TEdit;
  public
    procedure SetFocus(); override;
  end;

...

procedure TMyFrame.SetFocus();
begin
  Edit1.SetFocus();
end;
```

It works good if I directly call the frame's `SetFocus` method, but it has no effect when setting the form's `ActiveControl` property:

```
var
  Fr : TMyFrame;
begin
  Fr := TMyFrame.Create(Self);
  Fr.Align := alBottom;
  Fr.Parent := Self;

  ActiveControl := Fr;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write either

```
ActiveControl := MyFrame1.Edit1;
```

or

```
MyFrame1.Edit1.SetFocus;
```

If you want to work "at the frame level", you can intercept WM_SETFOCUS in the frame and set focus where you want:

```
private
    procedure WMSetFocus(var Msg : TWMSetFocus); message WM_SETFOCUS;


procedure TMyFrame.WMSetFocus(var Msg: TWMSetFocus);
begin
    Edit1.SetFocus;
end;
```

When you do that, you can just use

```
ActiveControl := MyFrame1;
```

Comment: Sure, but I'm trying to find a solution which works at the frame level, without referring to the subcomponent from outside the frame class (My frame is something like a compound component)

Comment: @Fabrizio OK, I edited my answer to add that feature.